# how to achieve 2 arrays from a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array generated from form.

```
[filters] => Array
        (
            [label] => Array
                (
                    [0] => label1
                    [1] => label2
                )

            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name1
                    [1] => name2
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => type1
                    [1] => type2
                )

            [table] => Array
                (
                    [0] => table1
                    [1] => table2
                )

            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => f1,f2
                    [1] => f3,f4
                )

        )
```

Now from the above array I want to generate following array

```
array(
    array(
        'label'=>'label1',
        'name'=>'name1',
         'type'=>'type1',
         'table'=>'table1',
         'fields'=>'f1,f2',
     ),
    array(
        'label'=>'label2',
        'name'=>'name2',
         'type'=>'type2',
         'table'=>'table2',
         'fields'=>'f3,f4',
     ),
)
```

How am I to achieve this? I tried using various array sort method but to no avail. Any help/suggestion are helpful. Thanks.

**Edit**
I've tried the following code:

```
foreach($_POST['filters'] as $ind => $filter) { 
    foreach($filter as $val) { 
        $array[$ind] = $val; 
    } 
} 
$arr[] = $array;
```

Comment: You don't need sorting methods, it's obvious. Just iterate and fill values.

Comment: use `foreach` or `for` loop and store the required data in a blank array.

Comment: I am trying it but to no avail. Any clue on how  to do it?

Comment: foreach($_POST['filters'] as $ind => $filter) {
 foreach($filter as $val) {
  $array[$ind] = $val;
  
 }
 
}
$arr[] = $array;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code this will work for you:

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr['filters'] as $index => $val){
    $i = 0;
    $depth = count($arr['filters'][$index]);
    if($i < $depth) {
        for($i; $i < $depth; $i++) {
            $newarr[$i][$index] = $val[$i];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarr);
```